# Create Issue error - TestLink Integration with JIRA

Tags: jira, testlink

I have integrated Testlink with JIRA. There are two bug management icons displaying one for creating issue and one to link an existing issue. Linking existing issue is working fine. But, Create Issue is not working as expected. When I click on "Create Issue" icon in the test link, I am getting this error. Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

```
Create JIRA Ticket FAILURE => 
com.atlassian.jira.rpc.exception.RemoteValidationException: Custom field ID 'minor' is invalid. 
- serialized issue:a:6:{s:7:"project";
    s:2:"TP";
    s:4:"type";
    i:1;
    s:7:"summary";
    s:92:"/Test Project/Test Suite 1/TC-1:Test Case 1 - Executed ON (ISO FORMAT): 2014-11-21 21:52:20";
    s:11:"description";
    s:177:"Execution ID: 22 Tester: admin Test Plan: Test Plan 1 Platform: FireFox Build: Build 1 Executed ON (ISO FORMAT): 2014-11-21 21:52:20 Execution Status: failed fsfsf";
    s:17:"customFieldValues";
    a:1:{i:0;
       a:2:{s:13:"customfieldId";
           s:5:"minor";
           s:6:"values";
           a:1:{i:0;s:7:"testing";}
           }
       }
    s:9:"issuetype";
    i:1;}
```